Dual Buck inverter confusion
I am having a slight confusion in the dual buck converter as given in the paper. This is a model for a PV inverter. This initially has a voltage DC-DC converter that maintains the bus voltage.

What is the purpose of the dual buck inverter? I mean why a buck? Does this buck further reduce the bus/sinusoidal voltage or is it only for the filtering purpose?

If it is for the filtering purpose, can I use a simple implementation shown below, because the flyback stage DC-DC converter is meant to make the Vbus so we don't need a buck specifically? Why are they specifying buck in it. My question might be very basic, but I have this confusion.


kindly help me get the difference between these two designs.

The shown "dual buck" circuit is a part of system which converts solar panel DC output to AC for feeding power to the grid. The idea to use same type of voltage control as used in buck DC to DC converters  to generate well controlled sinusoidal voltage with very little harmonic distortion. It's doubled to generate both polarities of the sine AC. Power grid owners do not accept much distortion, because harmonic components are harmful for numerous reasons.
In theory one could generate easily distorted waveform with a switching inverter and then try to filter out the harmonic components to fulfill the purity demands, but that's ineffective in the inverter.
But what's the difference? Your alternative is not symmetric. Otherwise it seems to be able to do the same job. It also needs DC input higher than the peak grid voltage. The lack of symmetry (inductor only in one output line ) makes it work as a powerful radio transmitter which uses the grid wiring as an antenna.

So you mean both serve the same purpose but the dual buck is much smoother

I have developed the spwm waves on the microcontroller. So if I simply give those four signals I would get a unipolar spwm at the output of the inverter. So can the same result be achieved if I use an LCL at the top and bottom both sides not only top side as shown in the second image. Can I have the same results beacuse this configuration is a way to produce an spwm wave...but mostly work is done in my controller and I only need to smoothen that out

I have misred your alternative schematic, It doesn't boost the voltage at all. It's an asymmetric version of the same as the "dual buck" version. I rewrote the answer. The actual trick of the dual buck system story is in the description of the control functions. Sorry for wasting your time.
